# How to avoid addActionMessage showing on all pages

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-validation

```
addActionMessage(" does not exist!");
```

how to avoid this message in JSP page showing all pages.

**JSP:**

```
<s:actionerror cssClass="MessageBox" theme="simple" />
</s:if> 

 <s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
     <s:actionmessage cssClass="MessageBox" theme="simple" />
 </s:if>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more context around your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added 
`addActionMessage(" does not exist!");` 
in all action method
You should use different messages in each method of action class to get diffetent messages.

Comment: private boolean showActionMessages;

public boolean isShowActionMessages(){
  return hasActionMessages() && showActionMessages;   
}where i want to write this method in action class or jsp

Answer (score 0):

ActionMessage is also `Collection<String> getActionMessage() {... }`.so you can use iteator method.try this,

```
    <s:iterator value="actionMessage" status="s">
          <s:set var="S1" value="%{actionMessage.get(#s.index)}"/>
              <s:if test="#S1.contains(' does not exist!')">
                    True
               </s:if><s:else> 
                     False
                </s:else>
     </s:iterator>
```

Comment: ... That seems kind of backwards; wouldn't it be better to just not add it on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

If the action has action messages then they will be shown. You need to change the logic to decide whether action messages should be shown. Create a method in the action class that returns `boolean` and is called when you need to test it. For example

```
private boolean showActionMessages;

public boolean isShowActionMessages(){
  return hasActionMessages() && showActionMessages;   
}
```

then change the `if` tag

```
<s:if test="showActionMessages">
     <s:actionmessage cssClass="MessageBox" theme="simple" />
</s:if>
```